# What's correct in my sentence: those or them?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing my project and I am stuck on this sentence:

> The task is to find domain walls and draw **THEM/THOSE** using different colors depending on the angle between adjacent domains.

I would write THEM, but MS Word keeps correcting it to "those". Which one is correct?

Comment: MS-Word isn't always right.

Comment: `Those` is the plural form of `that`. It could be acceptable here. But I highly doubt `them` is wrong. It is perfectly grammatical to use it after a verb to refer to something previously mentioned.

Comment: @Area51DetectiveFiction You're right about Word not always getting it right. To a native speaker's ear, *them* is **much** preferred here. Using *those* would sound off.

Comment: Word is often wrong. Turn off the grammar checker. It sucks egregiously, a view that is constantly being reinforced in these pages.

Comment: @DanBron: That's what I thought. I'd love to know why Bill Gates seems to approve it, though.

Comment: Search these pages for "grammar+checker" and you'll find over 50 responses that come to the same conclusion about these useless tools.

Comment: It stops complaining when you add "by" after them; it does not require it for _those_ - it means it sees "those using etc." as what is being drawn.

Comment: @Amphiteóth: Since when was the point of writing to make a stupid piece of software happy? The best way to stop Word's grammar checker from complaining is to shut the damn thing off.

Comment: @Robusto But grammar checkers do throw up some interesting grammar points though, and provide good fodder for grammar junkies! (See my answer below) :)

Comment: I wonder if MS Word would be satisfied if you put a comma after "them."

Comment: @Amphiteóth Where'd your question to me go? Anyhow, the answer to it is, no. It wouldn't be quite the same thing to use *by*. This would seem to indicate the method. Just the word *using* on it's own merely encodes simultanaeity, not method - although possible that's alo implied. :)

Comment: re: whether "by" trades idiomaticity for precision in context. @Araucaria Thank you, the nuance is interesting, I thought "by" was implied in cases like these when it is not used. So the grammar checker leverages "method" as a distinguising feature. I curate my comments to a high degree; I don't like loose ends and verbosity (in the comments). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I believe the reason that MS Word is having a problem here is that it is interpreting the string:

- them using different colors

... as an antecedent noun phrase, *them*, modified by a so-called reduced relative clause, *using different colors*,  where the whole phrase would mean:

- them [who are] using different colours.

Because we cannot usually have an accusative case antecedent for a relative clause, this would be ungrammatical. The word *those*, however, is not accusative case and is therefore a grammatical choice for such a construction:

- those [who are] using different colours.

As a noun phrase with a post-head modifier the example above is perfectly well-formed.

However, in the Original Posters example, *using different colours* is not modifying the pronoun *them*. Rather it is a gerund-participle phrase functioning as Adjunct. It is giving us more information about how the drawing was done.

In the example, *them* is functioning as the Direct Object of the verb *draw*. It is perfectly acceptable and grammatical. Many would argue that it is actually preferable to *those* here. The reason for this is that it is obvious that *them* refers to the domain walls. The reader needs no extra help identifying what is being picked out as the referent of the pronoun. Sometimes we might use *those* to express some attitudinal 'distance' from the thing being referred to. This is not the case here, so *them* might be the better choice of word.

Comment: Just come across this. Nice detective work (though it's usually Word wot dunnit).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I've given that perfectly decent question my up and reopen votes. Bit strapped for time tright now. All I'd say to the OP is that their sentence is perfectly fine from a grammar point of view!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Any chance of [a reopen vote here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442548/what-is-the-predicate-in-is-he-happy)

Comment: Sorry, I read your comment too late (last night) by the time I checked it was already opened. But I would have reopened, it's got an upvote from me though. [Thanks again btw](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442499/participial-phrases).